# Show that function does not have an integral

Tags: integration

i need to find the integral of $f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$

is there a way to show that this function doesn't have an integral?

I managed to show that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$, but I don't think that it's relevant in that case.

Comment: If one takes Cauchy princiole value it is zero, is that wrong ?

Comment: @Physor I haven't learned that yet

Comment: Check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: It is not Lebesgue-integrable because $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| d x = \infty$.

Comment: When you talk about the integral, what are you actually asking about? Are you asking about the antiderivatives? Or are you asking about the Riemann integral on some interval? If so, then you need to specify what interval you are integrating over.